Does filter have a way to export the "list" one element at a time?
On a practice exercise about prime numbers I found out that filter does not return a list itself and I need to do:
list(filter())

to obtain that list.
I do the exercise twice, once with a for loop:
def is_prime_for(n:init):
    if n <=3:
        return True
    else:
        m=list(range(2,n//2+1))     #+1 on the range for evade a bad result if 'n==4'    
    for i in m:
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    else:
        return True
value = 864203                     
print(is_prime_for(value))

other time with filter and lambda:
def is_divisible(num1:float,num2:float):
    if num1 % num2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def is_prime(num:int):
    if list(filter(lambda x: is_divisible(num,x), list(range(2,num//2+1)))) != []:
        return False
    else:
        return True
value = 864203                 #Same prime number that i found on google
print(is_prime(value))

Later I re-use the code for higher order functions and find that my "compact" filter and lambda function takes double time than for function to execute and much more with a "False" number (for example a number that can be divided by 2).
I can understand the double time because it goes through the list twice instead of once but in the case of the "False" number I thought that filter() is going to give me a empty list until the first number appear but that's not the case, list is "empty" until filtering ends.
Does anyone know a way to "update" filtered items list one as a time instead at the end of the filtering?
That's my code now with the higher order function that show the execute time:
import time  
  
def timeis(func):   #Decorator that reports the execution time.
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs): 
        start = time.time() 
        result = func(*args, **kwargs) 
        end = time.time() 
          
        print(func.__name__, end-start) 
        return result 
    return wrap 

def is_divisible(num1:float,num2:float):
    if num1%num2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
      
@timeis
def is_prime(num:int):
    if list(filter(lambda x: is_divisible(num,x),list(range(2,num//2+1)))) != []:  #+1 on the range for evade a bad result if 'n==4'
        return False
    else:
        return True
    
@timeis
def is_prime_for(n : int = 2):
    if n <= 3:
        return True
    else:
        m = list(range(2,n//2+1))
    for i in m:
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
    else:
        return True 
    
value = 864203           #A prime number that i found on google
#print(is_prime(value))    #That is used for prove the value find on google for no "false" positives
is_prime(value)
is_prime_for(value)


and that's the output:
is_prime 0.06304740905761719
is_prime_for 0.02378678321838379

**
EDIT
**
After testing with the code from answer and coments the code end like this:
import time
  
def timeis(func):  #Decorator that reports the execution time.
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs): 
        start = time.time() 
        result = func(*args, **kwargs) 
        end = time.time() 
          
        print(func.__name__, end-start) 
        return result 
    return wrap 

def is_divisible(num1:float,num2:float):
    if num1%num2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
 
@timeis
def is_prime(num:int):
    if any(is_divisible(num,x) for x in range(2,int(num**0.5+1.01))):   #Improved math with @Trincot answer and the help of @OneCricketeer on comments section
        return False
    else:
        return True

@timeis
def is_prime_all(num: int):                           #@Trincot answer
    return all(num%x for x in range(2, int(num**0.5+1.01)))

@timeis
def is_prime_all_mod(num: int):                       #@Trincot answer 'moded', it's faster on "False" numbers
    return all(num%x for x in range(2, num//2+1))

@timeis
def is_prime_for(n : int = 2):       #Improved math with @Trincot answer
    if n <= 3:
        return True
    else:
        m = range(2,int(n**0.5+1.01))
    for i in m:
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
    else:
        return True 
    
@timeis
def is_prime_while(n : int = 2):    #Improved math with @Trincot answer
    if n <= 3:
        return True
    else:
        x = int(n**0.5+1.01)
        i = 2
        while i < x:
            if n % i == 0:
                return False
            i+=1
        else:
            return True 
    
#value = 28122221                 #A prime number that i found on google
value = 28122222                #A "false" prime number for tests
#print(is_prime(value))  
is_prime(value)
is_prime_all(value)
is_prime_all_mod(value)
is_prime_for(value)
is_prime_while(value)


With an output with a "Real" prime number:
is_prime 0.00029087066650390625
is_prime_all 0.0001399517059326172
is_prime_all_mod 0.607919454574585
is_prime_for 0.0001266002655029297
is_prime_while 0.00017380714416503906

And the output if a number is not prime like:
is_prime 1.0013580322265625e-05
is_prime_all 7.152557373046875e-06
is_prime_all_mod 1.6689300537109375e-06
is_prime_for 1.1920928955078125e-06
is_prime_while 4.76837158203125e-07


Sounds like you want any() function, not filter(), if you expect short circuiting while iterating, e.g. if not any(is_divisible(num, x) for x in range(2,num//2+1))

You also only need to iterate up to the square root of num (rather than half + 1), and only in increments of two. (Or better still, use some caching to only iterate over primes up to the square root of num.)

@OneCricketeer Will any actually short circuit it? My understanding is that the full list is still calculated before the any is applied.

@MichaelCao According to the codeblock in the docs, it returns on the first truthy value https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any ; if a generator expression is passed, then the whole list would not be iterated

@OneCricketeer yep, thanks a lot, any() make it much cleaner than filter but it's still take the full list cause it's created before pased to any()

any() takes an iterable. This means that it can work on a generator, and only materialise the next value when it's required (lazyness). This means that it does not generate all the values first. It also stops at the first truthy value, which means that it does not need to generate/evaluate all the items if any are truthy.

Why the obsession with lists? Also the list(range(...)). Just iterate the range.

@nocomment it's not an obsesion, i'm on process to learn python (with a 30 days repo, link other "exercices" webs and some "changes" that i try myself for see if it works ) and, without experience, i'm trying to do as clean as i can and (on my code) if you try to filter the range, every time if return True because the filter return something like <filter object at 0x7f8dcc30fc40> and python take that expresion valid for an if. With any() it's works propertly any(is_divisible(num,x) for x in range(2,num//2+1))

There are a few things to improve here:

There is no need to apply list to the range for the second argument of filter. filter just needs an iterable as second argument, so a range is fine.

There is no need either to apply list to the result of filter when the goal is to verify that filter yields no results. In that case you can use any instead of filter. If you use the opposite condition to filter by, then you can use all.

The following pattern is something to get rid of:
if <boolean-expression>:
    return True
else:
    return False

Instead, just return the value of the boolean expression.

You have given is_prime_for a slight advantage by making it perform the modulo operation inline, while is_prime must call a function for that. To have an equal playing field, is_prime should also perform that operation in line.

Both implementations can do better by limiting the search for divisors to the square root of n. Any greater divisor would have a smaller counter part. For instance, if n has n//2 as a divisor, then it also has 2 as a divisor, so no need to test both.


That brings us to this version of the code:
@timeis
def is_prime(num: int):
    return all(num%x for x in range(2, int(num**0.5+1.01)))

Further improvements are possible.

Thanks a lot for your help, i learned too much with this.
I improved my code with your answer, the ones on coments section and a prove with a loop while. Yours is the fastest on a real primal number followed closely by while loop (bouth with your math expresion) but, i tried some cases for more understanding of the functions and, with a "false" primal number (divisible by 2), int() slowed (minimally, just 10^-5 from 10^-6 secs for yours and 10^-6 from 10^-7 for while) the code and the expresion (2//2+1) was faster cause it return an int directly without conversion.

Yes, if you run the code with n being an even number, then the exponentiation will make it slower. But there are many optimisations you can implement, like isolating the even-check so that you can step by 2 in the range (starting at 3 instead of 2), and this can be further improved by implementing a wheel, etc, etc. This really is a huge topic that has been covered in other Q&A. I just focused on your question here.
